ubuntu 22.04 freezing after user login screen
tried booting different kernels from grub menu;

6.8.0-40-generic               -freeze
6.8.0-40-generic recovery      -freeze
6.5.0-18-generic               -freeze
6.5.0-18-generic recovery       - working until 'resume from sleep' gave only a blank screen'.
I was able to install a working version of ubuntu 22.04 on a different disk. This used a different kernel so I used procedure in Ubuntu 20.04 won't wake from suspend or completely shutdown (answer posted by shizeon)
to add this kernel, 6.5.0-18-generic, while logged in to 6.5.0-18-generic recovery.
Rebooted selecting  6.5.0-18-generic kernel.

Problem solved. Posted fyi..

You only tried one 6.8 kernel. Since the kernel for 22.04 is now series 6.8 why not try another 6.8 kernel?

the one I tried was the only one in my grub menu. The link I referenced showed me how to add a kernel to the menu. So I added one I knew worked.
